# OnBuffer props in react-native-video is not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am using react-native-video for playing videos from url. I am using onBuffer prop to show loader if the video is buffering. But in my case onBuffer is not working. If the video size is large then in case of a slow network or unstable network video is taking time to play, so I want to show loader if the video is not playing but in buffering mode.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and i was able to fix this in android by following this suggestion: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1920#issuecomment-604545238

From what i understand, by default android uses android player which dont have these features. But ExoPlayer has lots features like buffering, adaptive bitrate etc.. So, we have to explicitly specify to use ExoPlayer.
Important part is to enable multiDex.

This is what the fix suggested and it worked fine:

If you are curois how to enable exoplayer then follow these steps:

create react-native.config.js with following content:

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-video': {
      platforms: {
        android: {
          sourceDir: '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

now enable multidex following this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

clean using gradlew clean and rebuild to make it work

Comment: But the docs asks to add these 2 lines in settings.gradle to use exoplayer:

include ':react-native-video'
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer')

Comment: Which one to use react.config.js or settings.gradle ? Neither of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing this all stuff in my application on buffering state you can simply check the state on buffer and display loader like this. You have to use a combination of `onLoadStart, onBuffer and onLoadEnd`, Below is an example of how you can also build your custom loader and display while buffering.
If you don't want to use my loader or this animation stuff remove that thing and render your own loader.

```
    class VideoPlayer extends React.Component {
       constructor (props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
          paused: false,
          buffering: true,
          animated: new Animated.Value(0),
          progress: 0,
          duration: 0
    }
  }
  handleMainButtonTouch = () => {
    if (this.state.progress >= 1) {
      this.player.seek(0)
    }

    this.setState(state => {
      return {
        paused: !state.paused
      }
    })
  };
  handleProgressPress = e => {
    const position = e.nativeEvent.locationX
    const progress = (position / 250) * this.state.duration
    const isPlaying = !this.state.paused

    this.player.seek(progress)
  };

  handleProgress = progress => {
    this.setState({
      progress: progress.currentTime / this.state.duration
    })
  };
  onBuffer = ({isBuffering}) => {
    this.setState({ buffering: isBuffering })
    if (isBuffering) {
      this.triggerBufferAnimation()
    }
    if (this.loopingAnimation && isBuffering) {
      this.loopingAnimation.stopAnimation()
    }
  }
  onLoadStart = () => {
    this.triggerBufferAnimation()
  }

  handleLoad = ({duration}) => {
    this.setState({
      duration: duration
    })
  };

  triggerBufferAnimation = () => {
    this.loopingAnimation && this.loopingAnimation.stopAnimation()
    this.loopingAnimation = Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(this.state.animated, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 1500
      })
    ).start()
  };
  render () {
    console.log('video player ', this.props)
    const { isShowingDetails, hideDetails, showDetails, thumbnailUrl, url } = this.props
    const { buffering } = this.state
    const BufferInterpolation = this.state.animated.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '600deg']
    })
    const rotateStyles = { transform: [{
      rotate: BufferInterpolation
    }]
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Video
          ref={ref => {
            this.player = ref;
          }}
          source={{ uri: url }}
          controls
          paused={this.state.paused}
          // poster={thumbnailUrl}
          onBuffer={this.onBuffer}
          onLoadStart={this.onLoadStart}
          onLoad={this.handleLoad}
          key={url}
          onProgress={this.handleProgress}
          style={styles.backgroundVideo}
          useTextureView={false}
          onVideoEnd={() => alert('Video ended')}
          bufferConfig={{
            minBufferMs: 15000,
            maxBufferMs: 50000,
            bufferForPlaybackMs: 2500,
            bufferForPlaybackAfterRebufferMs: 5000
          }}
        />
        <View
          color={Colors.appColor}
          style={styles.videoCover}
        >{
          buffering && <Animated.View style={rotateStyles}>
            <FontAwesome5 name='circle-notch' size={50} color='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)' />
          </Animated.View>
        }</View>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default VideoPlayer
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundVideo: {
    height: undefined,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    zIndex: 100
    // 2: 0
  },
  videoCover: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    zIndex: 10
  },
  controls: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    height: 20,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 5,
    right: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    zIndex: 10
  },
  duration: {
    color: '#FFF',
    marginLeft: 15
  }
})
```

Comment: @AmitTiwary What do you mean by Buffer is not working function is not called in the buffering state?

Comment: Can you make a snack on the expo with this issue? or can share minimum repo with this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onLoad` and `onEnd` prop of react-native-video to show loader.

For Example

```
<Video
    poster={/*uri*/}
    posterResizeMode="cover"
    source={/*source*/}
    onLoad={()=>/* set loader to true*/}
    onEnd={()=>/* set loader to false*/}
  />
```

Comment: I want to handle buffering. onLoad and onEnd works when video start and video end.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me.
Solution is to use exoPlayer instead of mediaPlayer.
when we install react-native-video package then by default it installs mediaPlayer which is better in case of just working with local media files.
But when we need to work with online videos then we need exoPlayer.

How to apply exoPlayer ?

This is well defined in react-native-video docs :
https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for your suggestion. Here are some SO posting guidelines that you may not be aware of. Link only responses are not considered answers by SO. As is, this is a perfect example of helpful content for the Comments section of a post. For most questions, Answers must contain exact code necessary to solve the OP's issue, preferably explaining important bits. Links are fine, if you also embed important info from the linked page into your post. Otherwise, if the page becomes unavailable, or its content changes, your post becomes useless & SO quality suffers. See StackOverflow.com/help

Comment: Please provide the steps you followed to fix the issue.

Comment: @Piyush see : https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video#androidsettingsgradle.    In manual android installation see the implemention of exo-player in android/settings.gradle.

Comment: If i use exoplayer then onload() never gets called. but if I use default media player then black screen with only audio. version 5.2.1